# Episode of Wonder Woman (1975) with some crystals as a core part of the plot?

Tags: dc, episode-identification, wonder-woman, wonder-woman-1975

Around 1990, they were broadcasting *Wonder Woman* (1975) in my country, and I believe it was in this series where there was an episode revolving around some crystals. Perhaps they were alien crystals? I can't remember exactly.

What I remember is they were powerful and perhaps they hypnotized people who saw them or something. And something else that I remember which isn't related to the plot is, I couldn't watch how it ended because I had to return from my grandmother house to mine, so I couldn't finish it watching it. It's possible that they were a set of 2 episodes that were related, and this episode I couldn't finish watching was the second one, but maybe I'm mixing this memory with another event.

Any ideas which episodes could be an episode (or 2) of *Wonder Woman* (1975) with some crystals as a core part of the plot?

Answer (score 2):

Is this *Wonder Woman* S03E14, **"[Spaced Out](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0750257/)"** (1979)...?

From IMDB:

> Master thief James Kimball steals three crystal lenses from the Torrance Aerospace plant but has to hide them in a crate in order to get out clean. The crate's destination is the Space Questicon in the L.A. Hotel Le Baron where Sylvester Grogan is setting up a display of Apollo moon rocks. Diana Prince is dispatched to find the stolen lenses and is staying at the same hotel. Kimball attends the convention in disguise to snatch back his loot. Meanwhile his employer, afraid Kimball will offer the lenses to a higher bidder has him shadowed as well.

From the [Wonder Woman Wiki](https://wonder-woman.fandom.com/wiki/Episode_314:_Spaced_Out):

> The crystals are designed to focus lasers for astronomy, but could easily be adapted to create deadly weapons.

Sci-fi fans may wish to note that the episode features a cameo from [Robby the Robot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robby_the_Robot).

Comment: The description doesnt ring any bells, but I would have to watch it. I'm positive that if I see an image of the crystals I would recognize if it's or not

Comment: The crystals appear in the above video https://youtu.be/3DONhv-nBwA?t=30 and again in better detail https://youtu.be/3DONhv-nBwA?t=87